# Stop voting to put Drupal questions on hold as "Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc."

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I see this more and more these days. There are questions like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/105313/16495) - not so good ones, maybe should be put on hold, maybe not. Doesn't matter. It is a question **about Drupal, Drupal-specific tools** (Views in this example), **Drupal-specific APIs** (here - Drupal AJAX implementation). And somebody votes to put it on hold as generic PHP question.

**Why?**

**Please don't!**

If question is just bad, downvote. If it's about code, but does not provide code, use custom off-topic close reason. If it's unclear, it's unclear. If it requires a whole tutorial (possibly including programming, but not about programming directly but about Drupal solutions) then it's too broad. There are reasons that apply more than one meaning *"This Views question is not about Drupal at all and is equally valid in any other PHP CMS"*. Well no, it isn't.

Comment: Bravo.  Ditto module-based questions being marked off-topic,  when they would produce very useful results for someone who can't find what they need to accomplish something.